# Sender Authentication Package Configuration Problem

Tags: marketing-cloud

We are trying to configure Sender's Authentication Package on Marketing Cloud. Found some useful links and tried following the steps provided but our vendor was kept telling us that the private domain is not provisioned.

For branding purpose, we have chosen to delegate a subdomain we currently own.
What we have done (steps by steps)

1. Identify an unused sub-domain
2. Goto https://senderauth.marketingcloud.com/ and provide all the information required including the sub-domain identified
3. DNS Entries were provided by SalesForce and we get our Network Administrator to update on our DNS server

Was wondering did we miss out any steps or done anything wrong? Thanks for sharing!

Comment: What domain are you trying to configure a SAP for?

Comment: Thanks Andrew, not sure if I get your question correctly - we are configuring SAP for RMM and Account branding purpose.

Comment: You were asking whether you have missed anything out. The process for setting up a SAP is as you describe. Whether you've missed anything out or done anything wrong would be largely to do with whether the DNS records your Admin has created are complete and correct. Without knowing the domain you're delegating, I couldn't say.

Comment: Hi Andrew, the subdomain we are trying to configure is propertyemail.simedarby.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The process for delegating your subdomain for use in a Sender Authentication Package is as you describe. You will either choose to ["self-host"](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/sender_authentication_package/maintaining_your_own_dns_records_for_your_sending_domain/) the various DNS entries required in your own zone file or simply [delegate by adding Name Server](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/sender_authentication_package/subdomain_delegation_guide_for_sender_authentication_package/) (NS) records in your zone file and have Salesforce Marketing Cloud create the myriad of DNS records required for you.

Either way, you should end up with TXT records like these using NSLookup to authenticate your emails (disregard the digicert line):

[image]

Your MX records should look similar to this for managing RMM - note this varies a little depending on the stack your account's hosted on:

[image]

There are a fair number of other records that your Admin or Salesforce will need to create to complete the job. With respect to your own domain, either configuration of DNS for the SAP has not been done or we're still waiting on propagation of the DNS changes to find their way around the internet:

[image]

I normally wait until these DNS records have been created and propagated before filling out the Saleforce SAP Form online. Their process is to just close your ticket immediately if the DNS is not correct.

Comment: Thanks Andrew - Finally manage to sort out. I missed out some of the entries and once that's done, everything works perfectly!